# Can't remove observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a observer in Main activity, when its value changes navigate to other page, so I only wanna it to observe once. But inside removeObserver, there is always an error, "Unresolved reference: confirmedAddressObserver". If I use key word this, "this" will refer to main activity, it doesn't work.

```kotlin
val confirmedAddressObserver = androidx.lifecycle.Observer<Boolean> {
                        if (it) {
                            navController.navigate(Screen.OnboardingTurnonScreen.route)
                            apiViewModel.confirmedAddress.removeObserver(confirmedAddressObserver)
                        }
                    }
                    apiViewModel.confirmedAddress.observe(this@MainActivity, confirmedAddressObserver)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should explicitly create the instance of anonymous class. This code will work correctly:

```
        val observer = object: Observer<Boolean> {
            override fun onChanged(value: Boolean) {
                if (value) {
                    navController.navigate(xxx)
                    apiViewModel.confirmedAddress.removeObserver(this)
                }
            }
        }
        apiViewModel.confirmedAddress.observe(this, observer)
```